# Difference between Hot redeploy in Play and automatic restart in Spring Boot

Tags: java, playframework, spring-boot, classloader

If I take a look at [Hot redeploy](http://jto.github.io/articles/play_anatomy_part2_sbt/) in Play and [Automatic restart](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart) in Spring Boot, it seems very similar. Is there any principal difference between implementation of these features in these projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are essentially the same in terms of implementation in that they both create a new application classloader to load in the new changes and discard the previous one.

Note that here are a couple of options for running a Play application to trigger reload:-

The following will trigger a rebuild and reload of classloader when a new request is received by the application, namely when you hit refresh in your browser. James Ward's plugin just saves you have to hit refresh.

```
activator run
```

The following will monitor your source directories for changes and will automatically re-compile any modified source on the fly. Although the server has recompiled the source and setup a new classloader you still need to do a refresh in your browser to see the changes (or use an extension like James Ward's).

```
activator ~run
```

Answer (score 3):

In Play it's out of the box, while in Spring Boot you have to install the [Dev-tools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3).

In Play you have to hit the reload button of your browser in order to reload but there is an [awesome plugin made by James Ward](https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh) which triggers a reload when you make changes to a file.

**Warning personal opinion:**

Working on both frameworks, using both plugins, the Play version is much cleaner and works better, save changes, see how the browser refreshes, immense productivity boost.

Also in performance, if your Spring application is a little bit bigger than usual, it takes a little bit longer, while in Play it's always fast.